# Google Maps Api v3 with API Key

Tags: ios5, google-maps-api-3

All,

Getting "REQUEST DENIED" when I try to access Google Maps Geocoding web service. Not sure why. The URL looks right to me and the Simple Access API browser key is valid and has both Maps v2 and Maps v3 turned on.

I realize the API key is no longer required in v3 so I have no idea how to get around the API limits using the web services via query string params.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MYAPIKEY&latlng=39.76144296429947,-104.8011589050293&sensor=true

When I remove the "key" parameter, it works but I need stats and don't wanna hit the API access limits so I need the key in there (I think)

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with geonames.org for this project. Much easier to deal with than Google.